# Exercise in arithmetic of a finite field

Tags: polynomials, finite-fields

I am in difficult in resolving this exercise in Galois Theory : "in $GF(2^5)$ calculates the product $(1,1,1,0,1)(0,1,0,1,0)$ , generator of $GF(2^5)^*$ ". 
I don't know how to proceed.. thank you

Comment: What is GF(2^5)? I've never seen this notation.

Comment: In Italy we use this notation : p^n is the order ... in this case 2^5 are 32 elements

Comment: Oh so this is the finite field $\mathbb{F}_{2^5}$? And you are trying to calculate the product of the two field elements $(1,1,1,0,1), (0, 1, 0, 1, 0)$ written as vectors over $\mathbb{F}_2$?

Comment: Yes, I know the polynomial therm that they represent ... but later there are some divisions to do with a polynomial of degree 5 irreducible

Comment: @Sempliner yes, $\mathrm{GF}(2^5)$ and $\mathbb{F}_{2^5}$ are the same thing

Comment: @Alessandro se puoi darmi una mano in italiano sarebbe ancora più semplice ^.^

Comment: @Alberto purtroppo non so rispondere alla tua domanda, non conoscendo molta teoria di Galois

Comment: Va bene :), nessun problema

Comment: Looks like you are writing the elements in terms of a monomial basis. The answer depends on the minimal polynomial. I hazard a guess that we are to assume that $t^5+t^2+1=0$, because that is the most common choice. Please confirm or correct and clarify!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Do you know what the multiplication by $(0, 1, 0, 1, 0) = (0, 1, 0, 0, 0) + (0, 0, 0, 1, 0)$ is given as a matrix with coefficients in $\mathbb{F}_2$? From this it should be fairly easy.

Answer (score 0):

I just know that $(0,1,0,1,0)$ represent $t^3+t$ polynomial ..
Ps: I m new here, is it possible upload image ? And how to write correctly the mathematical formulas?

Comment: Learn [latex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX) to properly write mathematical formulas.

Comment: Google "Math StackExchange LaTeX guide" for LaTeX help